# What is meant by diameter of a network?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, shortest-path

The diagram shown on [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28graph_theory%29) of the "*A graph with 6 vertices and 7 edges where the vertex no 6 on the far-left is a leaf vertex or a pendant vertex.*" has DIAMETER 4? right or wrong?

Definitions are

> The diameter of a graph is the maximum
>   eccentricity of any vertex in the
>   graph. That is, it is the greatest
>   distance between any pair of vertices.
>   To find the diameter of a graph, first
>   find the shortest path between each
>   pair of vertices. The greatest length
>   of any of these paths is the diameter
>   of the graph.
>
> Diameter, D, of a network having N
>   nodes is defined as the maximum
>   shortest paths between any two nodes
>   in the network
>
> Diameter, D, of a network having N
>   nodes is defined as the longest path,
>   p, of the shortest paths between any
>   two nodes D ¼ max (minp[pij length(
>   p)). In this equation, pij is the
>   length of the path between nodes i and
>   j and length (p) is a procedure that
>   returns the length of the path, p. For
>   example, the diameter of a 4  4 Mesh D
>   ¼ 6.

Comment: Where did you get the second definition from? And can you please quote it properly, all symbols etc?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### The Wikipedia Example

Looks like the diameter is 3 to me by definition.

[image]

The longest shortest paths have length of 3 edges, e.g. between `6-1` and `6-2`.

---

#### The Mesh Example

Here's your second definition, with some typographical correction so that it makes sense:

> Diameter `D` of a network is defined as the longest path of the shortest paths between any two nodes. For example, the diameter of a 4x4 mesh D = 6

Let's take a look at the 4x4 [mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph) example:

```
A---B---C---D
|   |   |   |
E---F---G---H
|   |   |   |
I---J---K---L
|   |   |   |
M---N---O---P
```

The longest shortest path has length of 6 edges, i.e. between `A-P` and `M-D`.

#### References

- [Mathworld - Wolfram/Graph Diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html)

  > The length of the "longest shortest path" between any two graph vertices of a graph.
- [Graph and Digraph Glossary - cudenver.edu](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/glossary.htm)

  > [Diameter](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/glossary.htm#Diameter): The diameter of a graph is the length of the longest chain you are forced to use to get from one vertex to another in that graph. You can find the diameter of a graph by finding the distance between every pair of vertices and taking the maximum of those distances.

#### See also

- [Computing Distances and Diameter](http://web.archive.org/web/20080330235019/http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~ute/220ft/graphalg/node19.html)

  - Has examples on weighted graphs

Comment: Assuming each edge is weighted `1`.

Comment: The weights are pre-defined for each edge. It's part of the graph.